# my Edit button not working results lbank, what seems to be the cause?

Tags: php

my Edit button not working results lbank, what seems to be the cause?

this is my 
admn_account.php
supposedly it should take me to the editing part, instead takes me to blank part
 and using mostly the include something by 1 index only like others would say to save up php files?

```
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Account Management</h2><hr />

<table class="table bg-dark"> 
    <thead> 
    <tr> 
        <th>#</th> 
        <th>First Name</th> 
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Middle Name</th> 
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Secret Question</th>        
        <th>Secret Answer</th> 
        <th>Email Address</th> 
        <th>Level of Access</th> 

     </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 


 <?php
        $stmt = $user_home->getUserList();

        if($stmt->rowCount()>0){

            foreach ( $stmt as $row ){

        ?>
            <tr> 
            <th scope="row"><?echo $row->userID ?></th> 
            <td><?echo $row->userfirstName ?></td>
            <td><?echo $row->userlastName ?></td> 
            <td><?echo $row->usermiddleName ?></td> 
            <td><?echo $row->userAddress ?></td> 
            <td><?echo $row->usersecretQuestion ?></td> 
            <td><?echo $row->usersecretAnswer ?></td> 
            <td><?echo $row->userEmail ?></td> 
            <td><?echo $row->usertype ?></td> 
            </td> 


            <form method="POST" class="userTransdoConfirm">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?echo $row->userfirstName?>" name="id">
            </form> 
            </td> </tr>     
        <?
            }
        }

   ?>
   </tbody> </table>
</div>
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2hZ6U64R  this are the codes for Update parts and activities btw

Comment: where is your code for edit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a wild shot because not all code is present, try changing the hidden input to the id of the user.

```
<form method="POST" class="userTransdoConfirm">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?echo $row->userID?>" name="id">
</form>
```